Development environment backup/restore with Time Machine?
I'm having my MacBook reinstalled by the IT dept, and want to avoid wasting days to get my environment back up they way I want it - devtools, various tools I installed through homebrew, git setup, ITerm2 settings, my IDE with all its config files, my git repos, and any other apps.
I was recommended to back up everything with Time Machine first. I've never used TimeMachine before, how should I approach this? What can I expect from restoring my backup after getting the computer reinstalled?
I will have the same OS version (Sonoma 14.6.1) before and after, but the reason for reinstall is related to our MDM solution.
Does Time Machine automatically apply your files so you end up where you left off, or does it simply let you pick individual folders to restore (in which case I wouldn't know how to selectively restore apps with config files in system folders etc). How do I go about to do this as efficient as possible?
Or am I better off biting the bullet and setting everything up fresh? Maybe just back up my home directory?

Your IT department needs to provide you input and support. Time Machine wipes everything they installed and you go back to what you have today, so they will likely need to redo their work. That being said, absolutely set up Time Machine as it will back up all your home folder and everything else that’s not excluded by rule or configuration on TM.


If you did not have MDM, then Time Machine would be a great solution. You connect an external disk, run a backup, wipe your computer, and select to restore from Time Machine during setup. Note that Time Machine is usually not a full disk restore byte-by-byte, instead it applies on top of the installed operating system.

With MDM, there's a chance it would restore the bad configuration so I'm not sure I recommend this approach versus setting up from scratch. Setting up from scratch has its benefits so I would strongly consider it.


